# Recyclerview fetch existing data after delete an item from adapter and does not update properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I try to implement a friend request feature in the fragment using custom adapter with firebase database. The problem is when a user accepts or delete someone request, it deletes from firebase but not properly update in the `RecyclerView`. this problems occurred in only runtime. If I refresh the page then my problem goes away.

Let I have two friend request. If I delete 2nd data then 2nd data will gone from `RecyclerView` but the problem is `RecyclerView` shows 1st data doubles. and if I delete 1st data then 1st data goes in the 2nd row and 2nd data came into the first row.

here is my database screenshot

[image]

Fragment class-

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView NotificationRecyclerView;
private NotificationAdapter adapter;
private List<Friend> friendList;

public NotificationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);

    NotificationRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.NotificationRecyclerView);
    NotificationRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    NotificationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
    friendList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new NotificationAdapter(getContext(), friendList);
    NotificationRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    readAllNotification();

    return view;
}

private void readAllNotification() {

    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FriendRequest");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Friend friend = snapshot.getValue(Friend.class);
                if (firebaseUser.getUid().equals(friend.getReceiverID())) {
                    friendList.add(friend);
                }
            }

            Collections.reverse(friendList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Custom Adapter -

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Friend> friendList;

public NotificationAdapter(Context context, List<Friend> friendList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.friendList = friendList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NotificationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_notification_item, parent, false);
    return new NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NotificationViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Friend friend = friendList.get(position);

    getUserInfo(holder.profileImage, holder.NotificationUserName, friend.getSenderID());

    holder.cancelRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FriendRequest")
                    .child(friend.getRequestID()).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    removeItem(position);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    friendList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return friendList.size();
}

private void getUserInfo(final CircleImageView prfileImage, final TextView NotificationUserName, String senderID) {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(senderID);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

            NotificationUserName.setText(users.getUserName());
            Picasso.with(context).load(users.getImageUrl()).into(prfileImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public class NotificationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView NotificationUserName;
    private Button cancelRequestButton;
    private CircleImageView profileImage;

    public NotificationViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        NotificationUserName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NotificationUserName);
        cancelRequestButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cancelRequestBtn);
        profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
    }
}
```

}

My APP Problems screenshot - 
let I have two request
1) if I delete 2nd data 1st data show doubles:

[image]
2) if I delete 1st data, 1st data goes into 2nd row and 2nd data came into 1st row:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your `recyclerView` and `adapter` in `onCreateView` which was not appropriate.You have to override the method `onViewCreated` then initialize your recyclerView and adapter.try like this

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView NotificationRecyclerView;
private NotificationAdapter adapter;
private List<Friend> friendList;

public NotificationFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);


return view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

  NotificationRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.NotificationRecyclerView);
NotificationRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
NotificationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
friendList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new NotificationAdapter(getContext(), friendList);
NotificationRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

readAllNotification();

}

private void readAllNotification() {

final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FriendRequest");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Friend friend = snapshot.getValue(Friend.class);
            if (firebaseUser.getUid().equals(friend.getReceiverID())) {
                friendList.add(friend);
            }
        }

        Collections.reverse(friendList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
```

Ok I just noticed you passed a parameter in `removeItem` method using  `holder.getAdapterPosition()` which is causing your problem.Try to pass the position which is provided by public void `onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NotificationViewHolder holder, final int position)`.So the basic error is when you are in `onBindViewHolder`  you don't need to use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` because `onBindViewHolder` already giving you the position

In your `removeItem` method use `notifyDataSetChanged` instead of `notifyItemRemoved(position)`
try like this

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NotificationViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  final Friend friend = friendList.get(position);
  holder.cancelRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FriendRequest").child(friend.getRequestID()).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                removeItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(context, "removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
}
  public void removeItem(int position) {
friendList.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: using notifyDataSetChanged method it's also not working sir :( . same problems happen

Comment: I just update my answer,plz check it.Hope it resolve your issues

Comment: Hello Sir, I already try it using removeItem(position) method in the viewholder class,but same problem occurred. This problems happen only in the runtime. If I click on the notification Icon and go again in the request tabLayout then the problem automatically goes away. If I have only one item then no problems happen.

Comment: I don't know what approaches did you try,but once again I update my answer did you try like this,like what I have written in my answer there?

Comment: yeah, I try exactly same thing sir :(

Comment: Can you paste your full class code here or just edit your question

Comment: ok I just update my answer one more time hope it resolve,plz give me a quick feedback

Comment: It's not resolve the problem and still same problem occurred :( .

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 removeItem(position);
```

with

```
 removeItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the same change for `    final Friend friend = friendList.get(position);
`, replace position with holder.getAdapterPosition(), usually the position that you get from the OnBindViewHolder() refers to the the position of the item within the adapter's data set, from what i've read in the documentation

Comment: yeah, i try it also but problem is not resolved , sir